# Spring Data JPA and defaults

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

in my db table I have a default value for an attribute like

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
   ...
   my_attribute INTEGER DEFAULT 0,
   ...
);
```

If I try to save my Java object with Spring Data repo.save(object) and then search it by id with findById(id), I get the object but the default value isn't set if I use Integer (not int).

Why it's not set?

How to fix it?

If I insert an entry in my table with SQL, the default 0 is set. Hmm...

Answer (score 2):

because `null` is also a value :

What happen in code?

When you call :

```
private Integer myAttribute;
```

the default value is `null` because Integer is an Object. so when you try to insert a null value, even with `DEFAULT 0` JPA will set `null` to `myAttribute`, the query should be :

```
INSERT INTO table0002 values (null);
```

..and when you INSERT a `null`, check what happen in the demo :

https://rextester.com/IJUT84677

The value is INSERTED! with `null` and not with `0`.

Now lets try another INSERT without specifing `my_attribute` in the query :

https://rextester.com/FGASH67830

We don't specify `my_attribute` in the query, so the default value is used. the documentation said :

[5.2. Default Values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/ddl-default.html)

> **A column can be assigned a default value. When a new row is created
>   and no values are specified for some of the columns, those columns
>   will be filled with their respective default values**. A data
>   manipulation command can also request explicitly that a column be set
>   to its default value,

---

To solve this you can just use :

```
private Integer myAttribute = 0; // set hard value in the code
```

Also beside you can use `NOT NULL` to make sure that the query will not insert NULL :

```
my_attribute INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

this can cause `violates not-null constraint` so be careful you have to set a default value non null when you call the insert, check what you get if you try that.

https://rextester.com/LMTTOO35342

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. If you set default value only in your database the answer can be in states of an entity. I mean you use data from the session where isn't set the default value. In this case, you can use method flush() (of EntityManager).